# How to make class with multiple Integers and Strings Parcelable?

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

I have following `Class` and i want to make it `Parcelable`
Problem is that when i read `isHidden and Counter` variable from `int[] arraySongIntegers` by method `in.createIntArray()` , i am getting an empty array of size 0 and BTW all the String variables are being read correctly . Please tell me how do i write all variables to `Parcel` and read it back properly.

```
public class Song implements Parcelable{
    public static long firstSongId;
    private long id;
    private String title ,mimeType, artist , dateAdded ,album;
    private int isHidden ,counter;    // 0 is false , 1 is true

 public Song(Parcel in){
    readFromParcel(in);
 }

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    int[] arraySongIntegers = new int[2];
    arraySongIntegers[0] = isHidden;
    arraySongIntegers[1] = counter;
    dest.writeIntArray(arraySongIntegers);


    dest.writeLong(id);

    List<String> l  = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(title);
    l.add(artist);
    l.add(album);
    l.add(dateAdded);
    dest.writeStringList(l);

}


public void readFromParcel(Parcel in){

    id = in.readLong();

    int[] arraySongIntegers = in.createIntArray();
    isHidden = arraySongIntegers[0];
    counter = arraySongIntegers[1];

    ArrayList<String> list = in.createStringArrayList();
    title = list.get(0);
    artist = list.get(1);
    album = list.get(2);
    dateAdded = list.get(3);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public  Song createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Song(in);
            }

            public  Song[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Song[size];
            }
        };
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you write it as an array rather than as individual ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my comment (there's no reason to make it an array)-  you need to read everything in the order you write it.  By reading the id first everything gets screwed up.

Comment: thanks . i didn't know that order actually matters .

Comment: Yeah, think of it as a byte stream-  that's not quite the implementation (it writes some other data) but its close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:
    http://www.parcelabler.com

Paste the class name + variables to the left textarea, click build and it will produce the right code for you.

For example if I have a class called myClass with 2 strings and 1 integer I would put this code to the textures:

```
public class myClass
{
    private String s1;
    private String s2;
    private int n1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bundle to save key/value pairs into the parcel. For this purpose use the `Parcel#writeBundle` method. As in this example:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt("id",id);
    data.putInt("year",year);
    parcel.writeBundle(data);
}
```